# How to get MAC addresses of all nearby devices in Android

Tags: android, arduino, esp8266, mac-address, nodemcu

Can anyone tell me how to find the MAC address of all devices nearby in Android, programmatically?

I am trying to design an Android app that is able to communicate data using broadcast messages via MAC address, to an Arduino microcontroller (ESP8266).
I would like the data communication between the two devices not to be tied to the connection (WiFi or Bluetooth). Therefore, I add to my initial question, if there are further ways of communication between Android and Arduino without connection.

Comment: Android has specific protections preventing non-System apps from gaining access to MAC addresses due to privacy concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an example of what you're trying to achieve (not mine):
https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery/blob/master/src/info/lamatricexiste/network/DnsDiscovery.java

Your second question is kinda badly worded I think.

1. Broadcast: "broadcasting is a method of transferring a message to all recipients simultaneously".
   Are you trying to send a message to all the ESP8266 (note that an ESP is not an Arduino) ? If so, use the dedicated broadcast address: which is all 1 on the host part of your IP address. So on a local network it would be `192.168.x.255`.
2. You could communicate via MAC address but this seems very inefficient. If you absolutely want to do it you have to dig into the lower layers of the TCP/IP stack (or other stack that uses the MAC address).
3. There is no way to communicate without a medium. You either need a wired or a wireless connection. Maybe you are referring to a the 'connectionless' way of sending packets like UDP. With UDP you can send a packet to your ESP without previous handshake (but you still need a medium: wifi or ethernet).

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear and comprehensive answer.
Do you recommend the linked project as a valid approach for scanning and identifying a specific MAC address? (MAC address of the NodeMCU).
Forgive me for formulating my questions but I am a beginner. However, in my project I want to avoid using an internet connection to communicate between the two devices, therefore, I would like the communication to be local.
Also, I don't want to use the Bluetooth protocol to communicate between the two devices, because I will use it for communication with other IoT devices (BLE Beacon).

Comment: I can't really say if that is the best way to do it but it seems like a valid way to do it. But I haven't tested it and I don't do much android. I think that you are looking for the Zigbee protocol. This is a dedicated protocol for IoT.

Comment: Hi @GiuseppeMondelli , did you find any solution to this? There is app (such as NetAnalyzer) on play store which apparently could get the neighbour mac address information. It's interesting because it works on Android 11. Getting the mac address is easy on Android 10 and below, but not on Android 11. Anyway, i am looking solution for the same issue too.

Comment: Hi @WachidSusilo, thanks for your answer but I found the solution by changing the philosophy of wireless communication using the Bluetooth BLE (low energy) network.

Answer (score 0):

Android and Arduino can communicate over BLE which requires no pairing or external infrastructure.

Comment: I would like to avoid using the Bluetooth protocol because I will use it later with other devices (BLE Beacon). However, if it is a valid alternative and allows the beacons to communicate simultaneously, thank you.